# Specifying fields in API using PHP

Tags: php, api

I have the following code which works;

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "appId=id&appKey=key&query=milk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print_r($response);
?>
```

Question is, how do i specify fields to be outputted in the results?
I have tried, `"appId=id&appKey=key&query=milk&fields=item_name, nf_calories"` but to no avail..

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No need to put it in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, just put it in the url. Adding a questionmark in between should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method, but I get no output at all..

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a question mark in between should do the trick really:

```
https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search?appId=id&appKey=key&query=milk&fields=item_name
```

And so on for the field names.

I've generally used this approach when using curl, you can take a look at it if you want:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}

function getUrl()
{
    $url = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search?appId=id&appKey=key&query=milk&fields=item_name";
    return $url;
}

function getData()
{
    $i = 0;
    $url = getUrl();
    $response = curl_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    if(!isset($data->data))
    {
        die("no data.");
    }
    $data = $data->data;
    return $data;
}
```

**EDIT:** Try an url like this:

```
https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/milk?results=0:20&fields=item_name,brand_name,item_id,nf_calories&appId=APPID&appKey=APPKEY
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your method above and I am just receiving the "no data" message..?

Comment: Did you change the $url acorrdingly with all the actual parameters?

Comment: I copied exactly what you have above except I put in the AppID and AppKey..but I just get "no data". The only information I want is matching food/drink names and their corresponding calories per 100g. Am I even using the right method to do this?

Comment: But you have already put in query=milk and fields=item_name above, so I just used that but no output was received?

Comment: query is not a valid parameter for /search. Try phrase=milk instead. Check https://developer.nutritionix.com/docs/v1_1 and Search for specific details. Check my edit. Remember to fix &appId=APPID&appKey=APPKEY.

Comment: @user3266484 Not sure if you saw my edited comment, test the new url and add your appid and appkey into it.

Comment: I tried using phrase=milk, i already tried searching for specific details yesterday, i used you edit but no luck. My project is due Monday so i can't spend anymore time on this, I'll just have to settle for something easier. Thanks a million for all your help anyway, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't have time don't worry about it :)